# How to convert DD-MMM-YY to YYYY/MM/DD in Big Query SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, date-formatting

I've one date format as DD-MMM-YY in one of my Big Query table as a STRING column (e.g 31-OCT-20).
Now I need to convert the format to YYYY/MM/DD in Date format to insert data to another table (e.g 2020/10/31).

Please help with the required format for Google Big Query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after trying a combination of `PARSE_DATE` and `FORMAT_DATE`:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d",PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%y','31-OCT-20'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date):

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%y','31-OCT-20')
```

Comment: Thanks..but the above gives result as 2020-10-20. But I need 2020/10/31 format.

Comment: It worked after trying a combination of PARSE_DATE and FORMAT_DATE: select FORMAT_DATE("%Y/%m/%d",PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%y','31-OCT-20'))